# Did I wire this furnace correctly?

Tags: hvac, thermostat, furnace, central-heating

I'm planning on connecting a nest thermostat in the next few days once my wifi is hooked up. In the meantime, I found an unused blue wire at the furnace and  hooked it up to the C. My current thermostat doesn't use C but it has the blue cable wrapped around unused. Did I wire it correctly on the furnace end? I'm still confused about the two brown wires on C and Y. Can someone explain please!! :)[image][image]

Comment: This is very close to another question you asked recently.  It would be better if you posted this new information by editing the previous question, where you already have comments and help.   Also, it's quite likely that the blue wire needs to be connected at both ends.

Comment: Duplicate: [Can I use this unused blue wire as my C wire for my new Nest thermostat?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/245232/can-i-use-this-unused-blue-wire-as-my-c-wire-for-my-new-nest-thermostat)

Comment: It is nearly identical, @jay613, and in general I'd agree with you (I even VtC at first), however, there is an error that needs to be corrected.

Comment: As a note for future reference, combining your images into one before posting makes it harder for us to zoom in on them to look at close details. It also makes it harder to reference them in comments/answers. Please simply post separate images, and if you're restricted in the number you can post, upload them individually to imgur.com and post the links - someone will embed them for you.

Answer (score 2):

No you didn't. Look at your original picture. Notice how the brown wire on the `C` terminal is wrapped clockwise around the screw?

[image: Correct wiring direction from original post]

However, when you put it back on with the blue wire, it's now wrapped counterclockwise.

[image: New image with wire wrapped in the wrong direction]

Don't ever do that - tightening the screw will back the brown wire out, leaving a sketchy connection that could arc. *All* wires under a screw should *always* be wrapped clockwise so that they're drawn *into* the connection as the screw is tightened.

Notice in that second image in the green box how the two wires are wrapped under the Y screw, both going in the same direction. That's what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your input! This makes sense! Sorry for the duplicate post. I'm new to this page and I'm still learning how to use it correctly. I appreciate all of your guys help!! I will correct the wires to being clockwise and then connect the other end of the blue wire to my Nest thermostat soon!

Comment: Take the [tour], @SharikhKhan, that will help you learn how things work around here. You can also browse through the [help] for more in-depth info.